# Boostrap glyphicon is outside of text field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to have a glyphicon inside of the input field but for some reason it's outside of text box.

```
<!-- Panel -->
<div class="panel panel-default hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
            <form>
                <p><strong>Enter your number and we'll text you a link</strong></p>
                <label class="sr-only">Phone Number</label>
                <input class="form-control phone-txt" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
                <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <p><strong>Or visit an app store to download now!</strong></p>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#">iOS</a>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="#">Android</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End panel -->
```

Comment: what icon your adding inside text field

Comment: The button in the form w/ the span element inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have that glyphicon attached to the button. You might try something like this...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control phone-txt" placeholder="Phone Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></span>
```

Comment: not complete, but you get the picture: http://jsfiddle.net/kirk_bishopp/yL169my6/

Comment: It's still outside the input text field. I have the attachments for the glyphicon inside a folder in my project.

I'm at a loss I have the form, and a input "text area", all I'm trying to do is have a submit button inside of the "text area"

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, you will see the icon in the input field. To give that an action, you may need to use some javascript that triggers on the onclick event possibly. I've never done that specifically, but don't see why it wouldn't work. I edited the fiddle and the onclick event does work on that span element...

Comment: For sure, glad I could help. Would you mind selecting this answer as the right one?? Thanks, Kirk

Comment: the jfiddle was the answer i was i looking for